# How use multiply ng-models in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have textarea with ng-model 'wordset' and ng-change="onChange()"

```
<div>
    <textarea ng-model="wordset" ng-change="onChange()"
              class="form-control app-word-set"
              placeholder="Enter Word Set" rows="4">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

I have button which added new textarea in this div. I needed that already added textarea includes the same on change method that my first textarea i have. But it should use ng-model...
I want to use on method in my angularJS controller that gets values from every textarea by foreach like this:

```
$scope.wordSetTextarea = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('app-word-set'));

$scope.onChange = function() {
angular.forEach($scope.wordSetTextarea, function(value, key) {
      console.log(value);
   });
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the AngularJS framework, multiple elements are added with the `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemArr">
    <textarea ng-model="item.wordset"
              ng-change="onChange(item,$index)"
              name="'item' + $index"
              class="form-control app-word-set"
              placeholder="Enter Word Set" rows="4">
    </textarea>
</div>

<button ng-click="addNewTextarea()">Add input</button>
```

```
$scope.itemArr = [{}];

$scope.addNewTextarea = function() {
    $scope.itemArr.push({});
};
```

New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so [data hiding problems] often shows up when these directives are involved ... [they] can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference -](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)
- [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)